# How do I get project root dir in the cmake install [code] section?

Tags: cmake

I use cmake 3.22.
I try to get root directory of the my project in the install[CODE] section in the my top level CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
...
project(myProject CXX)
...
install(CODE [[
  message(STATUS "PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
  message(STATUS "CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
  message(STATUS "CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
]])
```

I get the following outputs during installation `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`:

```
-- PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR:
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: /project_root/build/config_type_dir
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: /project_root/build/config_type_dir
```

But I need to get my `/project_root` path.

Doc says about `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` variable:

> This is the source directory of the last call to the project() command
> made in the current directory scope or one of its parents.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html

Is it a bug? Or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a bug? Or I do something wrong?

No, it's just that not all variables are available in `install(CODE)` segments. Here's a simple demo of detecting all the variables available there:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(example)

install(CODE [[
get_property(vars DIRECTORY PROPERTY VARIABLES)
foreach (var IN LISTS vars)
  message(STATUS "${var} = ${${var}}")
endforeach ()
]])
```

See in the terminal:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build
-- Install configuration: ""
-- CMAKE_ARGC = 4
-- CMAKE_ARGV0 = /home/reinking/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake
-- CMAKE_ARGV1 = -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=foo
-- CMAKE_ARGV2 = -P
-- CMAKE_ARGV3 = /path/to/build/cmake_install.cmake
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /path/to
-- CMAKE_COMMAND = /home/reinking/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake
-- CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND = /home/reinking/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cpack
-- CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING = FALSE
-- CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND = /home/reinking/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/ctest
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR = /path/to
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR = /path/to/build
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE = /path/to/build/cmake_install.cmake
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = /path/to
-- CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY = /CMakeFiles
-- CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME = Linux
-- CMAKE_HOST_UNIX = 1
-- CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME = 
-- CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = foo
-- CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = foo
-- CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE = 1
-- CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION = 3
-- CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION = 24
-- CMAKE_OBJDUMP = /usr/bin/objdump
-- CMAKE_PATCH_VERSION = 1
-- CMAKE_ROOT = /home/reinking/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24
-- CMAKE_SCRIPT_MODE_FILE = /path/to/build/cmake_install.cmake
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /path/to
-- CMAKE_TWEAK_VERSION = 0
-- CMAKE_VERSION = 3.24.1
-- UNIX = 1
```

So if you want to bake a variable into your install script, you'll have to generate the file. Here's one technique:

```
string(CONFIGURE [[
  set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR "@PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR@")

  message(STATUS "PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
  message(STATUS "CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
  message(STATUS "CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
]] install_script @ONLY)

install(CODE "${install_script}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside `install(CODE)` you specify a code which becomes part of the **other script**. That script will be executed from the **build directory** at installation stage via mechanism [cmake -P](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script). So, inside that script both `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` variables refers to the directory, from which the script is executed, and many project-related variables like `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` are simply not set.

If in the installation code you want to use values of variables from your **project**, then you need to embed these **values** directly to the code.

E.g., instead of [bracket argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument) you could use [quoted argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#quoted-argument):

```
install(CODE "
  message(STATUS \"PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}\")
  message(STATUS \"CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\")
  message(STATUS \"CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}\")
")
```

That way CMake automatically expands all `${...}` references to the current values of the variables.

Alternatively, if you do not want to escape double quotes (`"`), you could leave the code in a bracket form, but transform it via `string(CONFIGURE)` command:

```
# Create 'my_install_code' variable which has all variables expanded
string(CONFIGURE [[
  message(STATUS "PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
  message(STATUS "CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
  message(STATUS "CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
]] my_install_code)

install(CODE "${my_install_code}")
```